# Undefined 'this'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have JS class (React component) which was created for displaying forecasts:

```
class WeatherList extends Component {
  convertDate(date) {
    return new Date(date).toLocaleTimeString(['en-US'],
      {
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric'
      }
    );
  }

  renderWeather(data) {
    const temps = data.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp);
    const labels = data.list.map(weather => this.convertDate(weather.dt_txt));
    const chartData = {
      datasets: [{
        data: temps
      }],
      labels: labels,
    }

    return (
      <tr key={data.city.id}>
        <td>
          {data.city.name}
        </td>
        <td>
          <Line data={chartData} width="600" height="250"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className='table table-hover'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              City
            </th>
            <th>
              Temperature
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

But recently i'v ran into error: `this` in `this.convertDate(weather.dt_txt)` is `undefined` in the `renderWeather` function (which renders table row with Chart component).

i'm using webpack to compose all my file and also a babel library.

Comment: It depends on how `renderWeather` is called, so we'll need to see that.

Comment: Also the `labels = ` in your example seems like unrelated weirdness.

Comment: @loganfsmyth i updated my question to match my code fully.

Comment: A solution that does not require to create a new function is to pass the correct `this` value as second argument to `.map`: `this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather, this)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
    <tbody>
      {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
    </tbody>
```

To:

```
    <tbody>
      {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather.bind(this))}
    </tbody>
```

That way the method `renderWeather` will be called with the right `this` instead of `undefined`.

Alternatively, you can do the binding by not passing the function reference, but passing an inline function (using arrow syntax so you have access to the same `this`):

```
    <tbody>
      {this.props.weather.map(data => this.renderWeather(data))}
    </tbody>
```

Reference: [How does the `this` keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: You're welcome ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide a context to the convertDate method.

There are a few ways to do this:

```
// approach 1 (my favorite)
// declare method as an ES6 Arrow Function
class WeatherList extends Component {
  convertDate = (date) => {
    // method impl
  }
}

// approach 2
// bind all class methods to instance in constructor
class WeatherList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.convertDate = this.convertDate.bind(this) // once per method
  }
}

// approach 3
// provide context at call site
return data.list.map(weather => this.convertDate(weather.dt_txt).bind(this));
```

I'm not actually sure why class methods are not, by default, invoked with the class instance as `this`, but they are not. You'll typically run into this problem when a class method is attached as an event listener (e.g. in an element's `onClick`), but you'll also see it when providing a class method to an iterator like `Array.map`.

As a general rule, always define your ES6 Component methods as arrows. There are zero drawbacks, and the only time you wouldn't *need* the method to have `this` refer to the instance would be if the method was a pure function (i.e. it doesn't access `props` or `state`); and in those cases, it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I'm not using `context` inside `convertDate` function at all

Comment: I should have been clear: I don't mean React context. A lot of general-purpose JS documentation uses "context" to mean "the referent of `this` within a function or method." Perhaps `thisArg` is clearer?

Comment: I understood you, but i mean i was not using `this` inside that function. My mistake was that i haven't binded context even earlier, to the function which was calling `convertDate`.

Comment: If both methods had been defined as arrows, the problem would not have occurred.

Comment: Well, the problem was only with first function, that you didn't even mentioned. Anyway, thanks for commenting.